# Does index.android.bundle be necessary for android build release?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

When build release i always run `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle` and feel like the app run smoothly.
Does it correct?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are right, this command needs to be run every time before every release build.

If you don't want to type it every time you want to release build, you can write the following lines inside the `scripts` part of `package.json`:

```
"android-linux": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android".
```

For example I used in my `package.json` file like this:

```
{
  "name": "Widget",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android-linux": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.58.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.52.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason?

Comment: well it is given in the official doc https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#creating-a-release-build-in-android-studio that you need to execute the command to create a React Native bundle, which will be included with your native Android app.

Comment: i don't know the exact reason

Answer (score 3):

Yes.it is correct.

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --minify true --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

**--minify true** will help your app run smoothly.

Comment: Can you explain in detail?

Comment: let take an example like if there is one variable name "reactNative" in your application and used in many components with the same name. Now --minify true reduce your code like your variable name "reactNative" to a and replace it everywhere. By this, your code going to minify, take less memory in budling and reduce your app size.

Comment: @ParasKorat when --dev is false, it is automatically indludes --minify true so it doesn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (at least for react native >=  0.62), you **DON'T NEED** to run `react-native bundle` manually.

When using `./gradlew assembleRelease` this will already do it before finishing the build as stated in the log: `Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`.

I've also confirmed that myself and bundle is not written to the official RN doc [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android).

To go deeper, `index.android.bundle` is only used if you want to install the app through android studio without having the metro bundler running.